# how did not zoom content on printing when browser zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, printing

how did not zoom content on printing when browser zoom?
on zoom browser printing(use iframe) should not changed
i try:

```
document.body.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
```

but it's not correctly when page very long

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use next code:

```
const updateSizePrintPage = () => {
        let scale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;
        document.getElementById('print-page').style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
        document.getElementById('print-page').style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
      };
 window.addEventListener('resize', updateSizePrintPage )
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This could help to disable zooming overall.

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport'>
```

Comment: I was trying this, but that didn't help me

Comment: i use iframe for printing, maybe ignore scale in iframe