# how ignore browser zoom (ctrl+scroll) for iframe on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, printing

how ignore browser zoom (ctrl+scroll) for iframe on the page

i try:

try calculate scale use `window.devicePixelRatio` and change iframe zoom
`document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + 1 / window.devicePixelRatio + ')';`

Comment: Have you tried to use the meta tag both on the main page and on the page that's displayed within the `iframe`? Also, do you call the javascript approach from the main page or from the page in the IFrame?

Comment: yes, it is the same page but with another table and header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use next code:

```
const updateSizePrintPage = () => {
        let scale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;
        document.getElementById('print-page').style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
        document.getElementById('print-page').style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
      };
 window.addEventListener('resize', updateSizePrintPage )
```

and it works for me.
Please see this question: [how did not zoom content on printing when browser zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673904/how-did-not-zoom-content-on-printing-when-browser-zoom/48661378#48661378)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some trying I found a hacky solution to your problem. It uses the DetectZoom Library by tombigel ([link](https://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/)). Everything is done in the main document (for example index.html)

First, you have to add the following lines of CSS to your document

```
<style>
        #frame {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
            -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
</style>
```

Then, add an id (`frame` in my case) to your `iframe`, like this:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="...">
</iframe>
```

And, at the end of your document, add some javascript:

First, we'll need jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, the actual DetectZoom library (I've downloaded it and put it in one line of code here to make things easier, but you can of course put that thing in a separate js file).

```
<script>
    (function(root,ns,factory){"use strict";"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=factory(ns,root):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return factory(ns,root)}):root[ns]=factory(ns,root)})(window,"detectZoom",function(){var devicePixelRatio=function(){return window.devicePixelRatio||1},fallback=function(){return{zoom:1,devicePxPerCssPx:1}},ie8=function(){var zoom=Math.round(100*(screen.deviceXDPI/screen.logicalXDPI))/100;return{zoom:zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:zoom*devicePixelRatio()}},ie10=function(){var zoom=Math.round(100*(document.documentElement.offsetHeight/window.innerHeight))/100;return{zoom:zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:zoom*devicePixelRatio()}},webkitMobile=function(){var deviceWidth=90==Math.abs(window.orientation)?screen.height:screen.width,zoom=deviceWidth/window.innerWidth;return{zoom:zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:zoom*devicePixelRatio()}},webkit=function(){var important=function(str){return str.replace(/;/g," !important;")},div=document.createElement("div");div.innerHTML="1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>0",div.setAttribute("style",important("font: 100px/1em sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none; height: auto; width: 1em; padding: 0; overflow: visible;"));var container=document.createElement("div");container.setAttribute("style",important("width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; position: absolute;")),container.appendChild(div),document.body.appendChild(container);var zoom=1e3/div.clientHeight;return zoom=Math.round(100*zoom)/100,document.body.removeChild(container),{zoom:zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:zoom*devicePixelRatio()}},firefox4=function(){var zoom=mediaQueryBinarySearch("min--moz-device-pixel-ratio","",0,10,20,1e-4);return zoom=Math.round(100*zoom)/100,{zoom:zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:zoom}},firefox18=function(){return{zoom:firefox4().zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:devicePixelRatio()}},opera11=function(){var zoom=window.top.outerWidth/window.top.innerWidth;return zoom=Math.round(100*zoom)/100,{zoom:zoom,devicePxPerCssPx:zoom*devicePixelRatio()}},mediaQueryBinarySearch=function(property,unit,a,b,maxIter,epsilon){function binarySearch(a,b,maxIter){var mid=(a+b)/2;if(0>=maxIter||epsilon>b-a)return mid;var query="("+property+":"+mid+unit+")";return matchMedia(query).matches?binarySearch(mid,b,maxIter-1):binarySearch(a,mid,maxIter-1)}var matchMedia,head,style,div;window.matchMedia?matchMedia=window.matchMedia:(head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],style=document.createElement("style"),head.appendChild(style),div=document.createElement("div"),div.className="mediaQueryBinarySearch",div.style.display="none",document.body.appendChild(div),matchMedia=function(query){style.sheet.insertRule("@media "+query+"{.mediaQueryBinarySearch "+"{text-decoration: underline} }",0);var matched="underline"==getComputedStyle(div,null).textDecoration;return style.sheet.deleteRule(0),{matches:matched}});var ratio=binarySearch(a,b,maxIter);return div&&(head.removeChild(style),document.body.removeChild(div)),ratio},detectFunction=function(){var func=fallback;return isNaN(screen.logicalXDPI)||isNaN(screen.systemXDPI)?window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints?func=ie10:"orientation"in window&&"string"==typeof document.body.style.webkitMarquee?func=webkitMobile:"string"==typeof document.body.style.webkitMarquee?func=webkit:navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")>=0?func=opera11:window.devicePixelRatio?func=firefox18:firefox4().zoom>.001&&(func=firefox4):func=ie8,func}();return{zoom:function(){return detectFunction().zoom},device:function(){return detectFunction().devicePxPerCssPx}}});
</script>
```

And finally, let's add the functionality for the `iframe` to keep size.

```
<script>
    function refresh() {
        var zoomLevel = 1 / (window.detectZoom.device().toFixed(2));
        $('#frame').css({ transform: 'scale(' + zoomLevel +')' });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        refresh();
        $(window).on('resize', refresh);
    });
</script>
```

You can see a working example here: [click](http://twometer.de/test/) (This will redirect to a HTML document with similar content as described above. This HTML document is hosted at my own server, because I could not use IFrames on JSFiddle, but I have no viruses there. Promise ;)!)

Note that I haven't written the library DetectZoom, but only the last javscript code snippet that scales the `iFrame`.

Everything has been tested with Google Chrome 61, I don't know how well that thing works with other or older brosers.

Comment: I cant use some library try
let scale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;
document.getElementById('frame').style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
window.addEventListener('resize', smFn);
on page iframe really not change, but on print this frame - incorrect

Comment: With the method I proposed in my answer, the `iframe` scales correctly, but 
I don't know whether this is browser-dependant. But why can't you use a library?